# Jquery - how to increase value of top property for every element in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table, which has problems with absolute positioning for dropdown inside a `<tr>`. `div.wrapper` doesn't help much because it breaks the layout. I found an solution by increasing top += 100, but I do not know how to increase this value for each element one after another by the same value

So, I need class="services" id="1" to be top: 100; and id="2" to be top: 200;... id=3:300px,id=4:400, etc..

Example:

```
<tr data-id="1">
   <td><i class="expand"></i>First</td>
   <td>something</td>
   <td>something</td>
   <div class="services" id="1">
       <div class="tr">
           <div class="td">Service ID 1</div>
           <div class="td">bla-bla-bla</div>
       </div>
   </div>
</tr>
<tr data-id="2">
   <td><i class="expand"></i>Second</td>
   <td>something</td>
   <td>something</td>
   <div class="services" id="2">
       <div class="tr">
           <div class="td">Service ID 2</div>
           <div class="td">bla-bla-bla</div>
       </div>
    </div>
</tr>

.services{
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
}
```

I tried this one, but it doesn't work because it will be more than 10 elements per page

```
var row = $('tbody tr');

row.each(function(i){
    var first = $(this).find('.services');
    var second = row.eq(i + 1).find('.services');

    first.animate({top: '+=100px'}, 0);
    second.animate({top: '+=200px'}, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try selecting all the services in the page (provided they'll all respect the structure provided in your post):

```
$('.services').each(function(index, elm) {
    $(elm).animate({top: (100 * index) + 'px' }, 0);
});
```

You could also try:

```
$('.services').each(function(index, elm) {
    $(elm).css({top: (100 * index) + 'px' });
});
```

You may also adapt your current code:

```
var row = $('tbody').find('tr');

row.each(function(i){
    $(this).css({top: (100 * i) + 'px' });
});
```

Hope it helps.